# How to prove eigenvectors of a matrix exponential are the same as those for the matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

It's [relatively easy](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1635209/660634) to show that any eigenvector of an arbitrary $n \times n$ matrix $A$ is also an eigenvector of it's matrix exponential, $B = e^A$. But how does one show the reverse is true: that any eigenvector of $B = e^A$ is also an eigenvector of $A$?

Comment: This is not entirely true. For example you may have a matrix which has complex eigenvalues and whose exponential has real eigenvalues, and thus there is no way to relate the eigenvalues of the exponential with those of original matrix, even if you try to say, use a logarithm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A counterexample is
$$
A=\left[\begin{array}{cc}0&-2\pi\\2\pi&0\end{array}\right],\hspace{8mm}e^A=\left[\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\0&1\end{array}\right].
$$
Then for example $[1,0]^T$ is an eigenvector of $e^A$ but not of $A$.