# If $u$ is an eigen vector of $\exp(A)$ then $u$ is an eigen vector of real valued matrix $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, lie-algebras

If $u$ is an eigen vector of $\exp(A)$ then $u$ is an eigen vector (e.vector) of $A$.

Is it true for a $2 \times 2$ real-valued matrix $A$.

My try:
$\exp(A)$ is invertible so all e.values (eigenvalues) are non zero so we can write
$$\exp(A)=U(e^aI+N)U^{-1}$$ where $e^a$ is an e.value corresponding to the e.vector $u$.
Now I can write $$\exp(A)=U(e^aI+N)U^{-1}=U(e^aI(I+e^{-a}N)U^{-1}$$

So, even if I write $$\log(e^aI)+\log(I+e^{-a}N)=\log(e^aI)-e^{-a}N$$

How will I manage $U$ and $U^{-1}$. Help me here.

Btw, for complex case the statement is not correct. We can get a contradiction here

Let
$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 
         4\pi i & 0\\
         0 & 2\pi i\\
         \end{bmatrix}.$$

Then $\exp(A) = Id$ and $v = \begin{bmatrix}
1\\
1
\end{bmatrix}$ is an eigenvector of $\exp(A)$ but not of $A$.

Look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1635192/eigenvector-and-eigenvalue-for-exponential-matrix).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1635192/eigenvector-and-eigenvalue-for-exponential-matrix

Comment: My question is different $A$ is real-valued here.

Comment: The difference isn't that $A$ is real valued but that you are looking for the converse to that question

Answer (score 4):

This is not true: If $A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ then $A^{2n} = (-1)^nI_2$ and $A^{2n+1} = (-1)^n A$ so that
$$
\exp(\pi A) = I_2 \cos(\pi)
+ A \sin(\pi) = - I_2.
$$
Any nonzero vector is eigenvector of $\exp(\pi A)$, but not of $A$.

Comment: Indeed. Thanks. I fixed it.

Comment: I meant to identify the complex 1 with $I_2$ and the complex $i=\sqrt{-1}$ with $A$, so that $A^2=-I_2$ and the calculation $\exp(\pi A)=-I_2$ is equivalent to $e^{i\pi}=-1$. I believe the current choice works out. Thanks for spotting the initial typo.

Comment: Oh yes, I misread the exponents.